# Persist entity nosql (hadoop/hbase/hive)

Tags: java, hadoop, entity, hbase, persist

I'm new to hadoop and I want to persist an entity to a nosql database in my case is Hbase using hiveQL! 
I did all the configuration related to hadoop , hbase,hive and everything works fine using the shell
Now I'm trying to implement a class that allows me to persist an entity to hbase (CRUD operations)
So how can I define the database schema , which data base driver can I use! and if there is any other configuration should I put in my program!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a pretty hard time trying to understand your question, so my answer is going to be very generic.

You should start by reading a few HBase books:

- http://hbase.apache.org/book.html
- http://www.amazon.es/HBase-Definitive-Guide-Lars-George/dp/1449396100

You've got good JAVA examples for almost anything you need on Lars' repo:

- https://github.com/larsgeorge/hbase-book

In case you want to use HIVE you should start by reading this:

- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration

Comment: I couldn't explain this perfectly but I want to do CRUD opreations using java to hbase.

Comment: Then check out the JAVA examples on Lars' repo: https://github.com/larsgeorge/hbase-book

Comment: No problem, you can find all CRUD examples here: https://github.com/larsgeorge/hbase-book/tree/master/ch03/src/main/java/client